# I am looking forward to ...ing as well as?

Tags: grammaticality

> I am looking forward to meeting you as well as the eager for learning new things.

Is the above sentence correct and fine?

I mainly have problem with the form of the noun after (as well as). What I want to say is this:

> I am looking forward to meeting you, and also I am eager for learning new things.

In general, when are we allowed to omit some part from the second part of such sentences?

Comment: "I look forward to meeting you, and I am eager to learn new things."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look forward to meeting you and I am eager to learn new things.

look forward to + -ing  (meet + ing)

I am eager to learn new things. (NOT eager for learning)

We don't use 'for' before a verb to talk about purpose. Instead, we use to + infinitive.

She went to Canada to attend the conference. He is studying everyday to improve his English. I am going to New York to visit my grandmother.

[[ We can use  before a noun to talk about a purpose.

I went to Paris for an interview. He went to the pub for a drink. He is studying hard for the exam.

We can use  before a verb to talk about the purpose of a thing. (the reason why we use it)

We use an altimeter  measur height above sea level. That stuff is (used)  clean leather. The garden shears are used  clip the hedge. He wears these old trousers  paint.